# How do I retrieve all users from a GitLab deployment using the GraphQL interface?

Tags: graphql, gitlab, gitlab-api

I am trying to load user information from GitLab so that I can associate usernames with issues.  When querying for issues, the assignee username is not directly available.  Instead, a user ID is available.

If I execute this GraphQL query using the `/-/graphql-explorer` endpoint on my GitLab deployment:

```
query {                                                                                                                                                                                       
  users {                                                                                                                                                                                     
    nodes {                                                                                                                                                                                   
      id                                                                                                                                                                                      
      name                                                                                                                                                                                    
      username                                                                                                                                                                                
    }                                                                                                                                                                                         
  }
}
```

then 91 users are returned.  This is clearly not all users on the deployment, though.  There are users I know exist but which are not included in the result.  I can query for them individually using this GraphQL query:

```
query {
  user(username: "someusername") {
    id
  }
}
```

and receive a result which seems to correctly describe the user.

Why are some users omitted from the results for this query?  I know that large result sets require dealing with pagination but the default page size is supposed to be 100 and I am receiving fewer results than this.  Additionally, if I request `pageinfo` and ask for the users after the resulting `endCursor` I receive no items.

How do I submit a query that gets me **all** users?  Failing that, how do I submit a query that will get me all users which could be assignees for a a group (or, failing that, for a list of projects)?

Comment: I don't see any limits about there ([in source code](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/app/graphql/resolvers/users_resolver.rb) of GraphQL app).

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with some other kind of access control, then?  Is there a permission required to see some users in the listing?

Comment: Would like to know if you are admin of the repository? If yes, this thread may help you https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/197939#note_275761727 .

Comment: I am not an admin of any projects on the gitlab instance.  I am a "Maintainer" of several.

Comment: I updated the question to explain why I want the complete user list.

Answer (score 11):

From the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/getting_started.html#pagination) :

> By default, GitLab’s GraphQL API will return only the first 100 records of any collection. This can be changed by using first or last arguments. Both arguments take a value, so first: 10 will return the first 10 records, and last: 10 the last 10 records.

So you have to do the pagination yourself, your first query would be for example :

```
query {                                                                                                                                                                                       
  users(first: 10) {
    edges {
      node {                                                                                                                                                                                   
        id                                                                                                                                                                                      
        name                                                                                                                                                                                    
        username                                                                                                                                                                                
      } 
    }
    pageInfo {
      endCursor
      hasNextPage
    }
  }
}
```

Then use the `PageInfo` result values to know if you have more pages to fetch and the cursor ID to fetch the next page, for example you could get the following result :

```
...
"pageInfo": {
   "endCursor": "eyJpZCI6Ijc****************zNjk0MDUwMDAgOVRDIn0",
   "hasNextPage": true
}
```

So for the next page, you have to query :

```
query {                                                                                                                                                                                       
  users(first: 10, after: "eyJpZCI6IjcxMj**********************Ni4zNjk0MDUwMDAgOVRDIn0") {
    edges {
      node {                                                                                                                                                                                   
        id                                                                                                                                                                                      
        name                                                                                                                                                                                    
        username                                                                                                                                                                                
      } 
    }
    pageInfo {
      endCursor
      hasNextPage
    }
  }
}
```

And so on until `hasNextPage` returns `false`.

For more info about pagination and cursors, see GraphQL documentation : https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/

Comment: This makes sense but not as an answer to this question.  My query doesn't specify a limit so it should inherit the default limit of 100 but it doesn't receive 100 results, only 91.

Comment: I edited the question to be explicit about the pagination interaction.

Comment: Sorry missed that. I'm afraid I can't help. Maybe check users state (some users can be blocked or deactivated/expired, and as they do not consume a seat maybe they could be ommitted from the results, would be strange though...). Else as you pointed out it may be a permission issue... Good luck.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone would say the same as Yann39. As that is not what you're looking for, would [Contact Support](https://about.gitlab.com/support/).